# Chai assertion error if in text are hyphen

Tags: javascript, chai, cucumberjs

There are uncaught assertion error in Chai with Cucumber-js. If in the DocString there are a hyphen - assertion does not work.
So if I have scenario DocString, like

```
Then I see message:
'''
somewhat1
somewhat2
somewhat3 - somewhat4
'''
```

I cannot use `assert.equal` or a`ssert.include` assertions because recieve an assertion error, although both arguments is absolutely identical.
If I use DocString without hyphen, like

```
Then I see message:
'''
somewhat1
somewhat2
somewhat3
'''
```

there are no any troubles.

Why I recieve an error when use hyphen?
There are any idea how can I use hyphen right in DocString?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there was be trouble because on site use multiple templates with different types of hyphen.it was necessary to use hyphen-minus instead of a dash.